# Microsoft Dynamics 2011 SharePoint 2011 Integration Impersonation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

When integrating SP 2010 in CRM 2011 the CRM `Listwebpart` uses the user account which was used while installing the `WebPart`.

That means every `modified by` or `created by` attribute relating to documents uploaded through the `WebPart` are tagged with the `system account`.

How can we impersonate the operation as the specific CRM user in SharePoint?

I can't find anything about it on the net.

Comment: I don't think thats my experience, how are you uploading the document?